# Mysql - how to get two row values in one column?

Tags: mysql

These are the two values (i.e price & special_price)

[image]
My current query gives special_price but not price

[image]

query

```
SELECT parent.entity_id AS parent_id,
simple.entity_id AS simple_id,
simple.sku AS simple_sku,
cpp.rule_price AS rule_price,
cped.value AS price,
cpev.value AS simple_name
FROM catalog_product_entity AS parent
JOIN catalog_product_super_link AS link ON parent.row_id = link.parent_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity AS simple ON link.product_id = simple.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalogrule_product_price AS cpp ON cpp.product_id = simple.entity_id AND
cpp.website_id = (SELECT `website_id` FROM `store` WHERE `store_id` = 0)
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped ON cped.row_id = simple.entity_id 
AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` 
WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('special_price')) AND cped.store_id= 0
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev ON cpev.row_id = simple.entity_id
AND cpev.store_id = 0
WHERE parent.entity_id IN (9244) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have tried to add this to get price also

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped ON cped.row_id = simple.entity_id 
AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` 
WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price')) AND cped.store_id= 0

Comment: But the above query is not working

Comment: Perhaps provide an MCRE

Comment: any thoughts on valid answer ?

Comment: Any thoughts on providing an MCRE?

Comment: what does mcre means ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example